# Deriving formula for rolling a run of q consecutive identical rolls on a k-sided die within n rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to write a general formula for the probability of rolling/flipping a $k$-sided object $n$ times and having at least one occurrence of at least $q$ consecutive identical rolls/flips.

This began as an attempt to work out the probability of flipping a coin ten times and having at least one run of three or more identical flips.

In this example case, it is easy to determine the total number of possible outcomes with 10 coin flips -- $2^{10}$. What is not so easy is finding a simple way to count the number of favorable outcomes.

For instance, if you start by counting the number of flips with the first three being heads (HHH???????), there are $2^7$ possibilities. There are also $2^7$ possibilities for TTT???????.

The next few are not too difficult either.   For ?HHH?????? there are also $2^7$ possibilities, minus the $2^6$ possibilities you've already counted in the format HHHH??????. The same goes for tails.

The further you go down the line, the trickier it is to subtract the combinations you've already counted, especially when you get to ???HHH????, because then you've already counted possibilities of the type HHHHHH????, ?HHHHH????, ??HHHH????, but also possibilities of type TTTHHH????.
The further you go down the line from there, it gets even more complicated keeping track of what you've already counted.

Is there a simpler way to do this than trial and error, and can it be generalized to a formula (as my question asked) for any *k*-sided object, any number of flips/rolls, and any length of run?

I would like to see how this formula is arrived at, not just what the formula is. NOTE: I am very adept at understanding mathematical concepts, but vocabulary-wise I am not beyond basic self-taught calculus and high school advanced math. Thus I can track with you on a complex explanation as long as you explain (or perhaps link to explanations for) any foreign terms along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just give you some pointers to get started.  I haven't worked this out, so I don't know if you'll find a "nice" formula, but I can tell you that there's a better way than what you've been doing.

Precisely because of the difficulties with inclusion and exclusion that you've encountered, it's easier to count the sequences than do *not* have a run of $q$ identical outcomes.  Call a sequence "good" if no run of $q$ identical outcomes occurs in it.  Let $S_j^{(n)}$ be the number of good sequences of length $n$ than end in a maximal run of $j$ identical outcomes.  For example, $S_3^{(10)}$ is the number of sequences of length $10$ that end in a run of $3$ identical outcomes, but not $4$ identical outcomes.  Define $$S^{(n)}=\sum_{j=1}^{q-1}S_j^{(n)}$$  so that it is $S^{(n)}$ that we want to compute.

We have $$
\begin{align}
S_1^{(1)}&=k\\
S_j^{(1)}&=0,\ j>1\\
S_j^{(n)}&=S_{j-1}^{(n-1)}, 1<j<q\\
S_1^{(n)}&=(k-1)S^{(n-1)}
\end{align}
$$

The first two equations are clear.

For the third equation, note that a good sequence of length $n$ that ends in a run of $j>1$ can only arise from a good sequence of length $n-1$ that ends in a run of $j-1;$ of course, the next outcome must be the same a the one in the run, so it can only arise in one way.

For the fourth equation, a good sequence of length $n$ ending in a run of exactly $1$ arises from a good any sequence of length $n-1$ followed by any of the $k-1$ outcomes that is different from the last outcome of that sequence.

For given values of $n,k,q$ this allows you to work out the value of $S^{(n)}$ quickly, especially if you use a computer.  Then you just need to divide by $k^n,$ and subtract from $1.$

I suggest you try working out examples with $q=2$ and small values of $k$ to begin with, and see if you find any patterns.

Good luck.

**EDIT**

Corrected a typo.  There are $k^n$ possible sequences of length $n$ of course, not $q^n$.

Comment: Thanks! That certainly gives it an easier perspective! I'm still sorting through your answer, but what I can grasp of it so far makes sense, and I figured the $q^n$ was just a typo, no worries!

Comment: If there's anything you don't understand, feel free to ask.  The goal of the site it to build up a body of questions and answers that people can search when they have math problems, so it's always worthwhile to correct typos, both in questions and in answers.

Comment: Understood, I guess I'm still working through your equations at the bottom. Your definitions I understand, and the top equation (the number of possible single rolls with a run of 1 is simply $k$, the number of sides). However I'm still trying to track with you on the next two statements.

Comment: @Kevin I'll add a little more explanation.  Be a few minutes.

Comment: This page approaches the problem in much the same way you explained...I think I have what I need now! Thanks for the help! http://www.gregegan.net/QUARANTINE/Runs/Runs.html

Answer (score 2):

Starting with  the complementary  probability of not  seeing a  run of
length $q$ we have the generating function

$$-\frac{k}{k-1} + \frac{k}{k-1}
\sum_{p\ge 0} (k-1)^p (z+z^2+\cdots+z^{q-1})^p$$

We will be extracting coefficients $[z^n]$ where $n\ge 1$ so the
adjustment term in front does not contribute. Continuing we find

$$\frac{k}{k-1}
\sum_{p\ge 0} (k-1)^p z^p \left(\frac{1-z^{q-1}}{1-z}\right)^p
\\ =
\frac{k}{k-1} \frac{1}{1-(k-1)z(1-z^{q-1})/(1-z)}
\\ = \frac{k}{k-1} \frac{1-z}{1-z-(k-1)z(1-z^{q-1})}
\\ = \frac{k}{k-1} \frac{1-z}{1-kz + (k-1)z^q}.$$

Doing the coefficient extraction from this we get

$$[z^n] \frac{1}{1-kz + (k-1)z^q}
= [z^n] \frac{1}{1 - z(k-(k-1)z^{q-1})}
\\ = [z^n] \sum_{p\ge 0} z^p (k-(k-1)z^{q-1})^p
= \sum_{p=0}^n [z^{n-p}] (k-(k-1)z^{q-1})^p
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n [z^p] (k-(k-1)z^{q-1})^{n-p}
= \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/(q-1)\rfloor}
[z^{p(q-1)}] (k-(k-1)z^{q-1})^{n-p(q-1)}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/(q-1)\rfloor}
[z^{p}] (k-(k-1)z)^{n-p(q-1)}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/(q-1)\rfloor}
{n-p(q-1)\choose p} (-1)^p (k-1)^p k^{n-pq}.$$

We thus obtain for the probability the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{gather}
P_{k,n,q} = \frac{Q_{k,n,q}-Q_{k,n-1,q}}{k^{n-1}\times (k-1)}
\\ \quad\text{where}\quad
Q_{k,n,q} = \sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor n/(q-1)\rfloor}
{n-p(q-1)\choose p} (-1)^p (k-1)^p k^{n-pq}.
\end{gather}}$$

This formula  permits the computation  of the probability  using basic
arithmetic  and  binomial  coefficients  where  enumeration  will  not
suffice. For example, rolling a die with $16$ faces $10$ times with no
run at least four we obtain

$$P_{16,10,4} =
{\frac {4288021875}{4294967296}} \approx 0.9983828932.$$

Since we have computed the complementary probability we use
$1-P_{k,n,q}.$

Answer (score 1):

You can get a formula as well. Let's compute the number of sequences with no run of $q$ symbols. Such a sequence will break into blocks of the same symbol of length between $1$ and $q-1$. There are $k$ possibilities for the first block, and $k-1$ for each subsequent block.

Letting $a_n$ be the number of sequences with no runs of $q$, a little generating function magic shows that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n=\frac{k(x+x^2+\dots+x^{q-1})}{1-(k-1)(x+x^2+\dots+x^{q-1})}=k\cdot \frac{x-x^q}{1-kx+(k-1)x^q}
$$
To solve for $a_n$, let's first ignore the numerator. The $x^n$ coefficient of this can be shown to be
$$
\frac1{1-x(k-(k-1)x^{q-1})}=\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{n-r(q-1)}{r}(1-k)^rk^{n-rq}
$$
Here, we use the convention that $\binom{m}\ell=0$ when $m<0$, so the only finite summands are when $r\le \frac{n}{q-1}$. Putting this all together, the final answer is
$$
a_n=k\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{n-1-r(q-1)}{r}(1-k)^rk^{n-1-rq}-\binom{n-q-r(q-1)}{r}(1-k)^rk^{n-(r+1)q}\\
=\boxed{\sum_{r\ge 0}\Bigg[\binom{n-1-r(q-1)}{r}k^{q-1}-\binom{n-q-r(q-1)}{r}\Bigg](1-k)^rk^{n-q(r+1)+1}}
$$

Comment: Upvoted. I did not see your answer until I submitted. I have done the coefficient extraction computation that you cite.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Quelle coïncidence! +1 to you as well

Comment: I don't get the same probabilities when I implement your last closed form. My values are different. For example with three sides, twelve rolls and run length five I get ${\frac {18316}{19683}}$ and your formula yields ${\frac {1081540880}{1162261467}}.$

Comment: Perhaps I made a type while simplifying. Your formula is $(Q_{k,n,q}-Q_{k,n-1,q})/(k^{n-1}(k-1))$, while mine should be $(Q_{k,n-1,q}-Q_{k,n-q,q})/(k^{n-1})$. According to [this Mathematica code](https://tio.run/##XY8xC8IwEIX3/oqHUyIRjeJScdDBTVAcQ5QgBUNsSmPFQfzt9dIWLR2ScHfvvveSm@qW5aayV1PXR@UuAp5OedFI1zg9c5UAW@uL3Jq78piAlXRJjiAQ9JhJqhw/h7E7szguEbignTfNZwK7e1EE5afdlv7oFZK9ddnGP14ZTRozAdcaMopACaKW@preX6OMDT4ldOck@SrZm3AtBihSDHBDlGxRjLn2Kz8gEQ/B@kqNYsQUGAn0wsq5wFJgofVfFwOkja4XpSes6y8) they agree.

Comment: It is sure to be very minor since all the rest is the same. I think your generating function starts at $p=1$ which is correct and produced the $x-x^q$ term. I observed that we may start at $p=0$ as the difference is a constant which does not contribute to $[z^n].$ This looks correct. However if you do have a typo in your conclusion wouldn't you want to fix it? Your coefficient extractor is correct as well.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Okay, I found the problem! There is no error in my post; the problem is Mathematica (I assume you used this to check my formula?) defines `Binomial[n,k]` to be nonzero when n < 0. This is sensible, but is not the convention I used, which is also widely used. So for my summation to work, you need to set `B[n_,k_] := Binomial[n,k] * Boole[n >= 0]` and use `B` in place of `Binomial`.

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem. I entered your formula into Maple using your convention for binomial coefficients and the values agree with what I have. You do mention it in your post. My respect and I hope I wasn't too much trouble. I do have to say the convention ${n\choose k} = n^{\underline{k}}/k!$ is essential when computing binomial coefficient sums. Good work.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks for your attention as well, as I do indeed want to ensure my answer is typo free. Normally I agree with $\binom{n}k=n^{\underline k}/k!$, so that Pascal's identity holds for all inputs.